# Which is called first in Flutter StatefulWidget or the State class?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am new to the Flutter world and haven't built any real project in any other programming language.

I am trying to understand the flutter StatefulWidget and I was going through an article (read it [here](https://dart.academy/generics-in-dart-and-flutter/)), and got stuck at the below code.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text("Hello, "),
        const Text("World"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure out which class is calling the other class first!.

The MyWidget class is overriding the _MyWidgetState class,

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}
```

which eventually extends the State class,

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
```

and here the state MyWidget is itself a class!

Who is calling whom? Any reference to some documentation would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyWidget` class will call to `_MyWidgetState` when `createState()` run
Document about `createState()` method:

> The framework can call this method multiple times over the lifetime of
> a [StatefulWidget]. For example, if the widget is inserted into the
> tree in multiple locations, the framework will create a separate
> [State] object for later inserted into the tree again, the framework
> will call [createState] again to create a fresh [State] object,
> simplifying the lifecycle of [State] objects.

If you want to read more about life cycle of Widget, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479255/life-cycle-in-flutter)